# is a RowSet object scrollable by default?

Tags: java, jdbc, rowset

from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html) java tutorial:

> A RowSet object is scrollable and updatable by default, so by
>   populating a RowSet object with the contents of a result set, you can
>   effectively make the result set scrollable and updatable.

and then from [this subsequent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcrowset.html) java tutorial:

> Passing ResultSet Objects
>
> The simplest way to create a JdbcRowSet object is to produce a
>   ResultSet object and pass it to the JdbcRowSetImpl constructor. Doing
>   this not only creates a JdbcRowSet object but also populates it with
>   the data in the ResultSet object.
>
> Note: The ResultSet object that is passed to the JdbcRowSetImpl
>   constructor must be scrollable.

Why the result set needs to be scrollable if a RowSet object is scrollable by default? 
Is not that the main  advantadge of wrapping a ResultSet in a JdbcRowSet?

UPDATE: Referring directly to the JdbcRowSet interface:

> **One of the main uses of a JdbcRowSet object is to make a ResultSet object scrollable and updatable when it does not otherwise have those
>   capabilities.
>   **

quote from the same [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcrowset.html).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may read this: https://github.com/frolov/java-edu/issues/48

Comment: @RoshanJha it just report what I quoted from the same website and does not explain the conflict

Comment: @Rollerball Where does the text quoted in your update come from?

Comment: There is the link just after

Comment: @MarkRotteveel however again, from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcrowset.html

Comment: I found the same contradictory documentation and landed here.  I wish that they would clarify the tutorials on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JdbcRowSetImpl` is a - relatively - thin wrapper around a `Resultset`, so it demands that the `ResultSet` is also scrollable to be able to provide the required scrollability, if you don't want to or can't provide a scrollable result set you can use a `CachedRowSet`.

Contrary to what the tutorial you link to says, the [`com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/rowset/JdbcRowSetImpl.java.html) does not convert a non-scrollable `ResultSet` to a scrollable result set. The implementation simply wraps the `ResultSet` and forwards calls directly to it, so if the `ResultSet` is not scrollable then the `JdbcRowSet` isn't either. Same goes for the updatability.

The tutorial seems to be contradictory, because after the introduction that you can use `JdbcRowSet` to make a result set scrollable, it notes:

> A `JdbcRowSet` object created with a `ResultSet` object serves as a wrapper for the `ResultSet` object. Because the `RowSet` object rs is scrollable and updatable, `jdbcRs` is also scrollable and updatable. If you have run the method `createStatement` without any arguments, **`rs` would not be scrollable or updatable, and neither would `jdbcRs`.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: but why in the tutorial it's written that it mostly serves as a wrapper for resultsets non scrollable and not updateble while actually to instantiate a JdbcRowSet you need a ResultSet scrollable or updatable or both depending on your needs?

Comment: check out my UPDATE in the question.

Comment: The tutorial is talking about `RowSet` in general, but if you look at the specific reference implementation [`com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/rowset/JdbcRowSetImpl.java.html) it just forwards to the simplied `ResultSet`. To make non-scrollable result sets scrollable, you need `CachedRowSet`

Comment: actually talks about the JdbcRowSet interface which is implemented by a JdbcRowSetImpl

Comment: @Rollerball I updated my question, the tutorial is wrong, and even worse, it contradicts itself as you already noticed ;)

Comment: you update your answer not your question.:) ok ok all this contradictions must have been a left a little  preposterous  thinking. Cheers man, have a nice day.

Comment: @Rollerball Yes, I meant answer, I guess I need more coffee ;)